# When I use npapi to develop a textinput,How to submit it?

Tags: browser, webforms, npapi, network-security, ppapi

When I use npapi to develop a textinput to be a part of form,when I click submit button,How to submit the value of textinput developed by npapi?

Comment: I do not know of any way to do this.

Comment: I suppose you could have the npapi plugin inject it into a hidden field as it is changed

Comment: That, or just collect the value from an onsubmit handler.

Comment: Although i'd say avoid developing this as NPAPI in the first place. I don't know what exactly you want to do, but NPAPI is either going away (Chrome) or plugins get disabled by default (Firefox). Not to mention the distribution issues and that it won't work on mobile.